# Getting base 64 String of file gcs

Tags: download, base64, blob, google-cloud-storage

I would like to know if firebase(gcs) provide a way to download file's base64 String. I would want to pass this as an API response in java.

Whatever I have searched , I found gcs responding back blob. I want to convert this blob to base64 String. But `import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob` doesn't support

```
blob.getBytes()
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following code to download the content of a Google Cloud Storage file, then encoding that content to Base64:

```
package com.example.storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.BlobSourceOption;
import java.util.Arrays; 
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class EncodingSample {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // Instantiates a client
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of("your-bucket", "your-object"));
    System.out.printf("Data: %s %n", blob.toString());
    // Get object content
    byte[] content = blob.getContent(BlobSourceOption.generationMatch());
    // byte array to string
    String s = new String(content);
    // Bytes values
    System.out.printf("Array: %s %n", Arrays.toString(content));
    // Object content in string
    System.out.printf("Text: %s %n", s);
    // String encoded to Base64
    byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(s.getBytes());
    // Base64 bytes
    System.out.printf("encodedBytes: %s %n", Arrays.toString(encodedBytes));
    // Base64 encoded string
    System.out.println("String encoded: " + new String(encodedBytes));
  }
}
```

For more information regarding the `getContent` method, follow this [link](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/Blob.html#getContent-com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.BlobSourceOption...-).

Hope it helps